# Why does my Message-driven Bean stop processing messages?

Tags: java, ejb-3.0

When the server starts up, I can see it checking for messages, but sometimes it doesn't try to grab messages any more.

I haven't monitored it that closely to know the exact timing, but I know it's not even trying to check because I have it in debug mode and I don't see the message commands being executed at all; also, messages queued are not grab by message driven.

Here is my ejb-jar.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar id="ejb-jar_ID"
         version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">
 <display-name>MessageEJB</display-name>
 <enterprise-beans>
  <message-driven>
   <display-name>MessageBean</display-name>
   <ejb-name>MessageBean</ejb-name>
   <ejb-class>com.ecomm.ejb.mdb.MessageBean</ejb-class>
   <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type> 
   <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
   <message-destination-type>javax.jms.Queue</message-destination-type>
   <activation-config>
    <activation-config-property>
     <activation-config-property-name>destinationType</activation-config-property-name>
     <activation-config-property-value>javax.jms.Queue</activation-config-property-value>
    </activation-config-property>
    <activation-config-property>
     <activation-config-property-name>destination</activation-config-property-name>
     <activation-config-property-value>/queue/ExpiryQueue</activation-config-property-value>
    </activation-config-property>
   </activation-config>
  </message-driven>
 </enterprise-beans>
```

And jboss.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss>
 <enterprise-beans>
  <message-driven>
   <ejb-name>MessageBean</ejb-name>
   <destination-jndi-name>/queue/ExpiryQueue</destination-jndi-name>
   <resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>MessageBean</res-ref-name>
    <jndi-name>/queue/ExpiryQueue</jndi-name>
   </resource-ref>
  </message-driven>
 </enterprise-beans>
</jboss>
```

And ejb:

```
/**
 * Message-Driven Bean implementation class for: MeaageBean
 *
 */
@MessageDriven(
    mappedName = "/queue/ExpiryQueue",
    activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty(
            propertyName = "acknowledgeMode",
            propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"
        ),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(
            propertyName = "destinationType",
            propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue"
        )
    }
)
public class MessageBean implements MessageListener {
```

Answer (score 0):

Haii,

I'am a beginner in MessageListener, but i have my own perfect implementation...
I use Jboss 5.1 with hornetq
I think u have missing a annotation from your implementation....
maybe this one:

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destination", propertyValue = "queue/ExpiryQueue")
```

but in this situation i don't know why can be delivery a message sometimes....

i hope this can be help for U and